# Find out where the directory is in Linux?

Tags: 12.04, directory, find

When I executed the command to give the pid of my processes running, it gave me like this -

```
user@machineA:/$ ps -eo pid,command | grep exhibitor | grep java | grep -v grep
 1615 java -jar ./exhibitor-1.2.3/lib/exhibitor-1.2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar --fsconfigdir /opt/exhibitor/conf --hostname machineA
```

Now I saw this path in the above output -

```
./exhibitor-1.2.3/lib/exhibitor-1.2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Now I am trying to understand where this folder is `./exhibitor-1.2.3/` as I am not able to find out. Does this folder on the same ubuntu machine? Is there any way to find out that directory where it is?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the working directory of the process:

```
readlink /proc/1615/cwd
```

Beware that the process may have changed its working directory since it opened the file on the command line.

If the JRE doesn't close the JAR immediately after loading its content, you may find a symbolic link to it in `/proc/1615/fd`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
find / -name "exhibitor-1.2.3" -type d 2>/dev/null
```

or just

```
locate "exhibitor-1.2.3"
```